# AVR setting output repeatedly toggles the pin

Tags: avr

I'm writing a firmware for an ATMega328 and facing some issues. After searching in my logic for hours I could boil the code down to the most basic example and still have the problem.

I'm setting a pin to the value of a variable. Because I don't want to store to copies of a big array I'm setting the pin to the same value over and over again and if the variable changes, the pin gets set to a different state.

```
int main() {
    DDRB |= _BV(PB2);

    while (1) {
        PINB |= _BV(PB2);
        _delay_ms(50);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that with this code the pin toggles on and off every 50ms.

I could think of restructuring my code so I can detect change of the mentioned variable without the need of a copy.
But in the end I don't understand the problem, because I'm setting a bit of the output port to the same value over and over again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PINB` is *input* register (output register is `PORTB`).

And yes, writing `1` to input register `PINx` toggle bit in corresponding output register `PORTx` and pin value in modern (almost all for now) AVRs.

Comment: I'm facepalming as hard as I rarely do at the moment... And it was a good laugh! Thanks a lot, I'll never grow out of these stupid mistakes! ;)

Comment: It's common. I make similar (stupid) mistakes at almost constant rate all years I am working.